# Calculate MLE for ß parameters

Tags: r, math, genetic-algorithm

I'm new to R and have and stuck with an assignment. Would be really grateful if someone could help!

This is the task:
"Use a linear regression model to calculate the MLE(ß^) for the three ß parameters when using the linear regression mode to relate each of the L genotype markers with the phenotype (i.e. your R code must include the formula for the MLE).
Plot histograms for each of parameter estimates ß calculated for the L genotypes (i.e. three histograms!)"

I have 200 individuals and my Xd vector and Xa vector are:

```
> Xd
  [1]  0  0  0  0  1  0  0 NA  0  0  0  0  0  0  0 NA  0 NA  0  1  0  0  0  1  0
 [26]  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0 -1  0  0  1 -1  0 NA -1  0  0  0  0  0  0 NA  0  1
 [51]  0  0  0 -1  0  0  0 NA  0  0 -1 -1  0  0  0  0 -1  0  0 -1  0  0  0  0  0
 [76]  0  1  0  0  0  0  1  0  0  0 NA NA  0  0  0 NA  0  0 NA  0 -1  0  0  0 -1
[101]  0  0  0 NA NA  0 NA  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0 -1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
[126]  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0 -1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0 NA  1  0  0
[151] -1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0 NA  0  1  1  0 -1  0 -1
[176]  0  0  0  0 NA  0  0  0  1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0 -1  0  0  0  0 NA  0  0

> Xa
  [1]  1  1  1  1 -1  1  1 NA  1  1  1  1  1  1  1 NA  1 NA  1 -1  1  1  1 -1  1
 [26]  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1 -1  1  1 -1 -1  1 NA -1  1  1  1  1  1  1 NA  1 -1
 [51]  1  1  1 -1  1  1  1 NA  1  1 -1 -1  1  1  1  1 -1  1  1 -1  1  1  1  1  1
 [76]  1 -1  1  1  1  1 -1  1  1  1 NA NA  1  1  1 NA  1  1 NA  1 -1  1  1  1 -1
[101]  1  1  1 NA NA  1 NA  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1 -1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1
[126]  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1 -1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1 NA -1  1  1
[151] -1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1 NA  1 -1 -1  1 -1  1 -1
[176]  1  1  1  1 NA  1  1  1 -1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1 -1  1  1  1  1 NA  1  1
>
```

What i did was:

```
> Xmu=rep(1,200)

> X=cbind(Xmu, Xa, Xd)
```

Then I get the following error
**In cbind(Xmu, Xa, Xd) :
  number of rows of result is not a multiple of vector length (arg 2)**

What does that mean?? How do I calculate my MLE for my ß parameters? I would have proceeded like this:

```
Y <-  1 + Xa*1 + Xd*0 + rnorm(200,0,sqrt(1))

betas <- solve(t(X)%*% X) %*% t(X)%*% Y
beta_mu <- betas[1]
beta_a <- betas[2]
beta_d <- betas[3]
```

Also the "your code must include the MLE formula"-part confuses me!? Thanks

Comment: You have 199 Xa and Xd values, not 200.